# VirtualBox 5.1 installation issues Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, virtualbox, vagrant, ubuntu-16.04, secure-boot

I am using new to `Vagrant`. And stuck with `VirtualBox` installation with Ubuntu 16.04. Executing `vagrant up` command, gives the following error

> The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
>     available for the current kernel (4.8.0-46-generic) or it failed to
>     load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by
>     `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`
>       You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
>       5.1.18r114002

**ALREADY TRIED**

The issue is much common. The issue is said to be due to `secure boot` option enabled in the BIOS as it prevents third party modules ( i.e virtualbox) to be be loaded without digitally signed.

For signing the module so it can be properly loaded, I followed the [instructions here](https://stegard.net/2016/10/virtualbox-secure-boot-ubuntu-fail/) but I get stuck at

`mokutil --import /root/module-signing/MOK.der` which after asking password says

> Failed to enroll keys

Any pointers to the solution are highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to use Secure Boot? Why not disable it?

Comment: @StevenDavison, Yes that is an option. I can but I am trying without that